# How to ignore blank lines with linq when importing from CSV.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, csv

Since I have just started linq, the question may be considered noob

I have a scenario where I have to import  a remote csv and update it in database.

Previously I was using traditional approach i.e reading line by line splitting and the updating.

The query that I have written is as follows

```
var WItems = 
    ( from ln in File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).Skip(1)
    let columns = ln.Split(',')
    select new
    {
        Style = Convert.ToString(columns[0].Trim()),
        UPC = Convert.ToString(columns[1].Trim()),
        Description = Convert.ToString(columns[2].Trim()),
        FabricContent = Convert.ToString(columns[3].Trim()),
        CareInstruction = Convert.ToString(columns[4].Trim()),
        Color = Convert.ToString(columns[5]),
        Size = Convert.ToString(columns[6].Trim()),
        Price = Convert.ToString(columns[7].Trim()),
        Category = Convert.ToString(columns[8].Trim()),
        SubCategory = Convert.ToString(columns[9].Trim()),
        Stock = Convert.ToString(columns[10].Trim()),

    } ).ToList();
```

This query works well when there are no blank lines at the bottom, but throws error if there are blank lines at the bottom. My question is how can i split only those lines Which has something written or which is not blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add non emptiness check:

```
var WItems = (from ln in File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)
    .Skip(1)
    .Where(item => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
    let columns = ln.Split(',')
    select new { ... }).ToList()
```

Alternative - check if `columns` really contains 11 items:

```
File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).Skip(1)
    .Select(item => item.Split(','))
    .Where(cols => cols.Count() == 11).Select(columns => new { ... })
```

Comment: Thanx for checking for no. of columns.

Answer (score 3):

Add `Where` clause to your query:

```
from ln in File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)
           .Skip(1)
           .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
           // further code...
```